# (Take / Make) a U-turn?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Why do you say

> take a nose dive

> make a U-turn

not "make a nose dive" or "take a U-turn"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You "take" something that is already there.

When something does not exist, you make it.

So, if by "a turning" you are referring to a junction in the road, then you "take" that turn.

But a 'u-turn' is not something that is already there - it is a manouvre that you make.

Comment: That's a decent enough answer, but it doesn't really explain "take a nose dive" - the nose dive is not something that is already there.

Comment: Orthography varies, but [we almost always](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=took+a+nose+dive%2Cmade+a+nose+dive%2C%28nose-dived%29%2B%28nose+dived%29%2B%28nosedived%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctook%20a%20nose%20dive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmade%20a%20nose%20dive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28nose%20-%20dived%29%20%2B%20%28nose%20dived%29%20%2B%20%28nosedived%29%3B%2Cc0) just use ***nose[-]dive*** as a verb anyway, so we don't usually have to choose between making and taking with that one.

Comment: Regarding bodily motion, people can take a fall, including a pratfall, and I understand taking a dive is what boxers do when they have accepted a bribe to lose a fight.

Comment: This tries to explain something that doesn't need explanation.  It is just an idiom. There's no point trying to justify it.  The explanation doesn't explain  "take a nose-dive", so doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @stangdon That is an interesting one. Of course, a pilot would **make** a nose-dive. The context in which one might say "taken a nosedive" is if we were describing the direction something has taken, such as statistics. For example, "the share value took a nose dive" just means that the value went in a downwards direction. Its not the same as the OP's context

Comment: @JamesK No, I think you're wrong. There are other idiomatic uses where the above might not apply, but in this and similar contexts, it's sound.